# Camunda Modeler HTTP Connector doesn’t work

Tags: java, http, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I’m trying to make a post-call through the HTTP connector. I’ve followed the following [blog](https://medium.com/@stephenrussett/handling-government-business-processes-across-administrative-divisions-digitalstate-406f86d4fd56). Here’s how my BPMN file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_1l230i5" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="3.7.2">
  <bpmn:process id="MSTeam" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_18ctwbo</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_18ctwbo" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Activity_0yrauta" />
    <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_029y4fl">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0lfdhj8</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0lfdhj8" sourceRef="Activity_0yrauta" targetRef="Event_029y4fl" />
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Activity_0yrauta" name="Send MS Team Message">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:connector>
          <camunda:inputOutput>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="url">https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/19:0b51d90f1c6a45b6b9b094ee78d9f195@thread.tacv2/messages</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="method">POST</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="headers">
              <camunda:map>
                <camunda:entry key="Content-Type">application/json</camunda:entry>
                <camunda:entry key="Authorization">${token}</camunda:entry>
                <camunda:entry key="Accept">application/json</camunda:entry>
              </camunda:map>
            </camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="payload">
              <camunda:script scriptFormat="JavaScript">'{"body": {"content" : "Test from camunda"}}';</camunda:script>
            </camunda:inputParameter>
          </camunda:inputOutput>
          <camunda:connectorId>http-post</camunda:connectorId>
        </camunda:connector>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_18ctwbo</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0lfdhj8</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="MSTeam">
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_18ctwbo_di" bpmnElement="Flow_18ctwbo">
        <di:waypoint x="215" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="320" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0lfdhj8_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0lfdhj8">
        <di:waypoint x="420" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="532" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="179" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_029y4fl_di" bpmnElement="Event_029y4fl">
        <dc:Bounds x="532" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1v1tqko_di" bpmnElement="Activity_0yrauta">
        <dc:Bounds x="320" y="77" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

But when I run the application it generates the following error. To build this project I'm using the default project template from http://start.camunda.com/. Not sure what I have done wrong, I Would really appreciate any help/guidance thank you.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.ParseException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. | resource C:\Camunda\projects\WorkflowEngine.SOP.Unistad\emergency-evacuation\target\classes\MSTeam.bpmn | line 12 | column 73
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.jci.bmp.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.ParseException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. | resource C:\Camunda\projects\WorkflowEngine.SOP.Unistad\emergency-evacuation\target\classes\MSTeam.bpmn | line 12 | column 73
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1818) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:260) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1510) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ParseException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. | resource C:\Camunda\projects\WorkflowEngine.SOP.Unistad\emergency-evacuation\target\classes\MSTeam.bpmn | line 12 | column 73
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.exceptionDuringParsing(EngineUtilLogger.java:66) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:254) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:272) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.transformDefinitions(BpmnDeployer.java:105) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.transformResource(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:99) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.parseDefinitionResources(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:74) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.deploy(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:64) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:54) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:51) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:537) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer.deploy(CacheDeployer.java:51) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:67) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:65) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.deploy(DeployCmd.java:255) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:156) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:142) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:537) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.doExecute(DeployCmd.java:142) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:102) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:82) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:46) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.deployWithResult(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:102) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deployWithResult(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:270) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:266) ~[camunda-engine-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.autoDeployResources(SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.java:144) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.java:64) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:55) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:34) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or
> 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask.

What does your POM look like? Have you included these additional dependencies?

https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-http-connector-example/blob/2085bf2940c4192bfc03738177131bc2183bf1a1/pom.xml#L49-L56

Here is a working example project:
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-http-connector-example